# Variable update bug with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function to change my div text with some "typer" effect plugin.

The problem is, when I change my variable (containing the text), I need to refresh the entire page to see the text changing.

```
function promp() {

    var a = reta();

    if (a == 0) {
        zoomneg();
    } else {
        zoom();

        if (a == 1) {
            var str = "Text";
        } else if (a == 2) {
            var str = "Text 2";
        } else if (a == 3) {
            var str = "Text 3";
        } else if (a == 4) {
            var str = "Text 4";
        }

    }

    $(".element").typed({
        strings: [str],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        contentType: 'text'
    });

};
```

Any way to change the variable `str` every time my `var a` changes? The other parts of my function works when I change the value, the problem is just in this variable.

Thanks!

Comment: When does the `a` variable change? Or, what variable does change?

Comment: You can create object, add 'a' as a field and overwrite 'a' setter function that would execute required code block.

Comment: Every time I click on the screen. If I click left, the variable value goes -1, if I click right, +1. This function works when `a` change, just the `str`value can't work.

Comment: Assuming the promp functions executes, str only gets assigned if a is 1, 2, 3 or 4.  My suggestion is to console.log a before the first if statement.

Comment: Thanks, Will. The console.log return the a value correctly, but the variable still the same.

Comment: @ZecaNovaes - So what values did you get just before the $(".element").typed statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is a one of possible solutions using getter and setters that calls a function to handle change in value.

```
function zoomFn(a) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return zoomneg();
    }
    zoom();
}

function getTextByVal(a) {
    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            return "Text";
        case 2:
            return "Text 2";
        case 3:
            return "Text 3";
        case 4:
            return "Text 4";
    }
    return null;
}

function handleValueChanged(a) {
    zoomFn(a);
    $(".element").typed({
        strings: [getTextByVal(a)],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        contentType: 'text'
    }); 
}

var o = {
    set a(a){
        this._a = a;
        handleValueChanged(a);
    },
    get a(){
        return this._a;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Kaspars, but I can't use this code. Nothing wrong with  console.log, but the functions stop working that way.